# How do you set maxSockets in Node.js when using Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Is there a way to modify the Node.js [maxSockets](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_agent_maxsockets) setting when using the Express framework?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Somewhere after you do `var http = require('http')`, just add `http.globalAgent.maxSockets = x` (where 'x' is the number of sockets you want).

Please note that if you are making requests over https, you will need to set maxSockets for https as well.

```
var https = require('https');
https.globalAgent.maxSockets = your_val_here;
```

Comment: I never do require('http') though, just require('express').

Comment: Okay, then require it! :) Like it says, it's a global setting (for that process), so however you set it, express will use that setting.

Answer (score 25):

From version v0.12.0 maxSockets set to Infinity

> maxSockets are no longer limited to 5. The default is now set to Infinity with the developer and the operating system given control over how many simultaneous connections an application can keep open to a given host.

[Node v0.12.0 (Stable) release notes](http://blog.nodejs.org/2015/02/06/node-v0-12-0-stable/)