# Node.js V8 Garbage collection dropping connections

Tags: node.js, express, garbage-collection, v8

I was testing my JSON Rest API built using express.js with Siege. 
10 Concurrent users to start with. I was also monitoring the RSS memory usage in the server using this command

> watch -n 0.2 'ps -o rss $(pgrep node)'

I can see the memory increasing as the requests hit the server, It reaches around ~110000 and then instantly it goes back to normal.

The problem is at this point siege get's an error:

> [error] socket: 67633152 connection refused.: Connection refused

I believe this is bacause of the garbage collection and it stops everything (blocking process).

Is there any way to do this gracefully ? I want as much availability for the API as possible.

Another fact that worries me is, the memory-usage is not decreasing ( When there are no connections ). It stays where it is and only resets when it reaches that ~110000 mark. Isn't V8 Garbage collector supposed to kick in periodically? Am I missing something? ( Special configs for production maybe ). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Keep in mind that node.js may garbage collect memory (e.g. free it internally), but not give it back to the OS so it is available for reuse, but still shows as node.js memory if you look at overall process usage.  If you really want to see what node.js is actually using vs. freed for reuse, you have to look internally with node.js tools, not externally.

Comment: It seems unlikely that garbage collection led to a connection refused.  It seems more likely that you may have hit a limit in concurrent connections and you may want to increase that limit if your server can handle more at a time.

Comment: @jfriend00 is it a express.js setting or an os setting ?

Comment: @jfriend00 Yeah, but why is the memory drop visible when I start getting connection refused message in Siege? it should be linked, right?

Comment: It's an http module setting.  See what `http.globalAgent.maxSockets` is set to and perhaps increase it.

Comment: Also see this: [How do you set maxSockets in Node.js when using Express?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307837/how-do-you-set-maxsockets-in-node-js-when-using-express).

Comment: @jfriend00 It seems like the default value is Infinity.

Comment: That depends upon the version of node.js.  You should `console.log()` what it is set to in your app just to rule it out.

Comment: My console.log prints out Infinity.

Comment: Then, I'm out of ideas without being able to debug and observe it myself.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have an update, I ran the server without forever and was able to catch an Uncaught exception .   `Uncaught Exception Occoured
Airbrake: Uncaught exception, sending notification for:
Error: EMFILE, open '/srv/qa/logs/NodeApp.log'

/srv/qa/beartooth/src/node_modules/airbrake/lib/airbrake.js:314
  cgiData['process.memoryUsage'] = process.memoryUsage();
                                           ^
Error: EMFILE, too many open files`

Comment: @jfriend00 It may not be the V8 after all. I am using Winston module for logging, I am closing the handlers after use ( log.close() ). And I have no idea why airbrake didn't send me the notification.

Comment: Sounds like something is leaking file handles and eventually you run out.